# Importing Modules with Hydrogen in Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, atom-editor, hydrogen

I can run the code but trying to use the Hydrogen package in Atom I have problems importing some (not all) modules and I do not why. I do use Hydrogen with Python3.6 and i did install all needed modules with pip3.

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import sklearn

ImportError: No module named sklearn

Comment: Try restarting the Atom once. Also try with `sudo pip3 install ...`

Comment: did not help...

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is to do with where the kernel is starting. In the Hydrogen settings, look for the option **'Directory to start kernel in'**. The default is to always start in the directory in which Hydrogen was first invoked. If you have installed modules in a different working directory, then they will not be found, unless you change this option to **'current directory of the file'** (restart required)

You can check your `sys.path` to see where the kernel is looking for modules. If all else fails, you can manually move the installed packages to the 'site-packages' folder, whose location is revealed by `sys.path`.

I thought pip would put the packages in the right place by default, but maybe not - especially if you have virtual environments set up.

You can use the command `pip show <package name>` to get the path to which pip has installed the package in question.

Comment: I have the same problem as above. You are spot on, but this doesn't give a satisfying fix. in ipython, sys.path gives pointers to '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', but in Hydrogen sys.path gives pointers to  '/Users/r8t/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages'. 
How do I get Hydrogen set up to just use the same homebrew installed python3 my terminal does?

Comment: just found something that worked in this situation--update hydrogen, and restart everything